# Генерация всех форм слова с использованием АОТ на C++

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста с решением проблемы: я написал код основываясь на [АОТ](http://www.aot.ru/index.html) который по-идее должен анализировать слово и выдавать все его формы. Вот мой код

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <comdef.h>
#include "windows.h"
#include <iostream>
#import "C:\Rml\Bin\Lemmatizer.tlb"
using namespace std;
using namespace LEMMATIZERLib;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    _bstr_t main_form;

    CoInitialize(NULL);
    //  creating and loading Russian dictionary
    ILemmatizerPtr  piLemmatizer;
    HRESULT hr = piLemmatizer.CreateInstance(__uuidof(LemmatizerRussian));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        cout << "Fatal Error: Lemmatizer creation failed";
        return 1;
    }
    // loading dictionary into the memory
    hr = piLemmatizer->LoadDictionariesRegistry();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        cout << "Fatal Error: Lemmatizer loading failed";
        return 1;
    }
    // lemmatizing a word
    {
        IParadigmCollectionPtr piParadigmCollection = piLemmatizer->CreateParadigmCollectionFromForm("мыла", 0, 0);
        //  print possible lemmas
        for (int j = 0; j < piParadigmCollection->Count; j++)
        {
            main_form = _bstr_t(piParadigmCollection->Item[j]->Norm);
            CharToOem(main_form, main_form);
            cout << main_form << endl;
        };

    }

    {
        IParadigmCollectionPtr piParadigmCollection2 = piLemmatizer->CreateParadigmCollectionFromNorm(main_form, 1, 1);
        cout << piParadigmCollection2->Count << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < piParadigmCollection2->Count; ++i)
        {
            _bstr_t form = _bstr_t(piParadigmCollection2->Item[i]->Norm);
            CharToOem(form, form);
            cout << form << endl;
        };
    }
    // destroy the dictionary
    piLemmatizer = 0;
    CoUninitialize();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Но результаты выполнения CreateParadigmCollectionFromNorm просто главная форма. Как сделать, что бы оно выдавало все формы?

Текущий консольный вывод:

```
МЫЛО
МЫТЬ
1
МЫТЬ
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```

Comment: А что такое AOT? Если это какая-то сторонняя библиотека, вам лучше спросить у её разработчиков.

Comment: @VladD АОТ (http://www.aot.ru/index.html) -  библиотека по автоматической обработке текста. Довольно популярная и очень давно разрабатываемая. Разработчиков я тоже спросил и жду ответа.